# How to make open sourced scripts 'installable'?

Tags: bash

I've finished a little useful script written in Bash, hosted on github. It's tested and documented. Now, I struggle with how to make it `installable`, i.e. where should I put it and how.

It seems other such projects use make and configure but I couldn't really find any information on how to do this for bash scripts.

Also I'm unsure into which directory to put my script.

I know how to make it usable by myself but if a user downloads it, I want to provide the means for him to install it easily.

Comment: If there are no additional files, no installation is needed. Just put in anywhere in your $PATH (usually into `~/bin`) and `chmod u+x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard for this because most of the time, a project isn't a single script file. Also single file scripts don't need a build step (the script is already in an executable form) and configuration usually comes from an external config file (so no need for a `configure` script, either).

But I suggest to add a comment near the top of the file which explains what it does and how to install it (i.e. `chmod +x` +  copy to folder).

Alternatively, you could create an installer script which contains your original script plus a header which asks the user where she wants to install the real script and which does everything (`mkdir`, set permissions with `sudo`, etc) but it really feels like overkill in your case.

If you want to make it installable so the package manager can easily install and remove (!) it, you need to look at the documentation for [rpm](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-rpm1/) or [Debian packaging](http://wiki.debian.org/IntroDebianPackaging). These are the two most used package managers but they can't install a script per-user (so it would probably end up in `/usr/bin`)

Answer (score 0):

instruct them to create a file named after the script in their home directory, chmod ug+x the file so it has executable permissions than put the script inside the file, don't forget the #!/bin/bash up top of the vim. This example is a script to copy a file, archive the copied file than remove the copied file leaving only the original file and the archived file.

```
#!/bin/bash
#### The following will copy the desired file
cp -r /home/wes/Documents/Hum430 /home/wes/docs

#### Next archives the copied file
tar -zcvf Hum430.tar.gz /home/wes/docs

#### and lastly removes the un-archived copy leaving only the original and the archived file.
rm -r /home/wes/docs
### run the file with ./filename (whatever the file is named)
```